# Scanning generated QR code on Android Device when running expo run:android command does nothing

Tags: android, react-native, expo, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to create BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) proof of concept with expo and for that I need a physical device (simulator doesn't support BLE).

When I run npm start, it works and I can scan QR code on my physical Android device, but it gives me some kind of error.

Then I followed this:

https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/bluetooth-1

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx

And now with expo run:android it doesn't throw an error, but when I try to scan generated QR code on expo application on my Android smart phone, it does nothing (it redirects me to the home page of the expo app).

Have I missed something? Is it possible to test my app using expo run:android command on my physical Android smart phone?

Comment: I never used expo, but why do you need a QR-Code for BLE?

Comment: There is an expo client app you can install on your physical device.  Using this app, you'd scan the QR code generated in the terminal and that would run the app on a physical device, with hot reloading enabled.

Comment: I need a physical Android device to test BLE. QR Code is generated when running your code.

Comment: I installed expo app on my android and I scanned qr code with it and it redirects me to home page, it does nothing.